# Ubuntu 18.04 with unity - Alt+Shift to switch keyboard language layout fails on resume from suspend

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, suspend, keyboard-layout, input-language

I have Ubuntu 18.04 but I installed unity with it.

I have configured switching keyboard languages using <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> using the **Text Entry Settings**.

However, whenever I restart the computer and the OS starts, it does not work. If I go to the settings again, the <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> still appears there, however only when I clear and re-set this it works again, until I restart again.

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
```

returns:

```
['grp:lalt_lshift_toggle']
```

This left alt and left shift I configured with the GNOME Tweak Tool as I found in another question, but it did not help either.

I found that this problems occurs only after the computer wakes up after being suspended. If I restart the computer then it works well and <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> successfully changes the keyboard language.

Did anyone face this issue? Can you help me to solve this annoying problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and show us the output from the command `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Thank you, I edited the question

Comment: Then try to remove it: `gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options` (my thought is that there may be a conflict)

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I tried it, it doesn't help.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson, I updated the question, I found that it happens only after computer wakes up after it was suspended. If I restart the computer then the ALT+SHIFT works fine and changes the language.

Comment: Are you using GDM or LightDM? If the former, and considering that you are using Unity, you may want to install and switch to LightDM.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson how can I check that? I am  not sure which one I am using

Comment: You can run `cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager`. If that shows `/usr/sbin/gdm3`, `sudo apt install lightdm unity-greeter`, switch to `lightdm` when asked, and reboot.

Comment: Hi @GunnarHjalmarsson, it shows /usr/sbin/lightdm

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas. Maybe a bug.

Comment: Any results with the problem? I got the same and out of ideas.

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: (Using Unity Desktop on 18.04): I added a third language and changed the shortcuts to F9 and F8, restarted and now it mysteriously works

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found anything better than changing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd> in **Text Entry Settings** and it's still working after wake up